# Выполнить скрипт до того, прежде чем пользователь увидит содержимое страницы

Tags: javascript

```
const data = {
    int: function(){
       ****
    }
}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => data.int());
```

Таким образом запускаю скрипт тогда когда браузер принял документ но все еще не отобразил. Вопрос немного в другом. Смущает, что запускаю объект как то отдельно...

Во первых почему не работает так

```
window.onDOMContentLoaded = () => data.int();
```

Эстетически смотрится куда лучше, в случаи

```
window.onresize = () => this['content_p'];
```

Работает... Почему в одном случаи не работает, в другом работает?

Возвращаясь к вопросу. Возможно ли как только объявляем класс, тут же его запустить как только браузером будет принят документ. То есть выполнить код как одно целое, а не отдельно от него?

Comment: Думаю будет интересно https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded

Answer (score 0):

Не имею притензии к ответу от Игоря лишь добавлю если хотите что нибудь покрасивее то можно прочитать [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded)

```
window.onload = ()=>{....}
```

Добавлю что данный метод вызовется после DOMContentLoaded

Comment: читаем: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event  --- "Значительно отличающееся от него событие load используется для отслеживания только полностью загруженной страницы. Широко распространённой ошибкой является использование load в ситуации когда DOMContentLoaded является более подходящим, будьте внимательны."

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я что-то напутал? Я лишь указал что есть другой вариант. И не указываю что данные метод идентичен DOMContentLoaded.

Comment: Нет, это не *другой вариант.*

Comment: Нельзя почесать себя левой рукой не левой рукой

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я думаю что каждый имеет право на свою точку зрения. Вы считаете одно я другое

Comment: Можно если рука не ваша

Comment: Часто вы чешете себя чужой рукой?))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нет но и задачи такой нет чесать левой не левой. Бред да и только. Слышать такое от человека

Comment: Вот и у ТС тоже нет такой задачи

Comment: Я вот не согласен "Эстетически смотрится куда лучше, в случаи

window.onresize = () => this['content_p'];"

Comment: Ну и какой метод вы предложите сюда?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вот вы холиварите непонятно почему. Я вам повторяю что данный метод не является аналогом контекст лоада. А лишь эстетически красивого по взгляду ТП методом

Comment: Который отчасти возможно решит аналогичную проблему. Мы же содержимое метода не знаем ток что спорить тут не очем

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Если спор разрешился незатруднит ли вас снять минус с ответа